# Json Deserialized Stream Return Type

Tags: json, http

Hi i have a stream returned from a http response. i have deserialized it as Object(obj) and wanted to check the type of obj to MyObject or string or double. Is the procedure wrong or my concepts are wrong. Please help.

```
DataContractJsonSerializer obj = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Object));
        Object Obj = obj.ReadObject(_stream) as Object;
        Product p = new Product();
        List<string> ls = new List<string>();
        List<DisplayProduct> displs = new List<DisplayProduct>();

         if (Obj.Equals(p))
            Console.WriteLine("PRODUCT");
        else if (Obj.Equals(ls))
            Console.WriteLine("LIST OF STRING");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("DISPLAY PRODUCT LIST");
```

Answer (score 0):

Rain,

You can use the 'is' or 'as' keyword, instead of doing what you're trying to do.

The difference is that `as` operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion is not possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception. Consider the following expression:

```
expression as type
```

It is equivalent to the following expression except that expression is evaluated only one time.

```
expression is type ? (type)expression : (type)null
```

Example of how you would use `as`:

```
       Derived d = new Derived();

       Base b = d as Base;
```

By contrast, the `is` expression evaluates to true if the provided expression is non-null, and the provided object can be cast to the provided type without causing an exception to be thrown.

The `is` keyword causes a compile-time warning if the expression is known to always be true or to always be false, but typically evaluates type compatibility at run time.

Here's how you might use `is`:

```
if (obj is MyObject)
{
}
```

Comment: Done.Is served the purpose as required.

Comment: Just a tip since this is your first time: You should vote up and accept answers that answer your question. This will convey to people who want to answer your future questions that you appreciate their time etc. :)

Comment: oops.. sorry. dint know that!